# resize an image before upload to server with typescript, in .net core web app project

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core

How to resize image before upload to a server with typescript in .net core web app project.

```html
<form method="post" class="md-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="FileUpload" asp-action="Index">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="inputdefault">foto</label>
            <input type="file" name="files" class="form-control-file" accept="image/*" required />
        </div>
    </div>
   
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-bold form-control" type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use some graphics processing nuget packages, such as Magick.NET.Core-Q8, you can read this article, there are many dependency packages for graphics processing, I hope it will help you:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-image-processing/

Comment: @Chaodeng
thx, but
I need a solution in typescript , to do it on the client side.